# Coloring $\{1,2,...,2n\}$ elements in red and blue, such that if $i$ is red, $i-1$ is also red.

Tags: combinatorics

The purpose is to find the number of ways to color $2n$ following integers in red and blue, such that if $i$ is red, so is $i-1$.

I tried to use Inclusion-Exclusion principle, but I got stuck in the calculations.

It is a little tricky.

I am trying to count the number of cases where there are $k$ bad tuples $\color{blue}{i-1}\color{red}{i}$.

I need to get ${2n-k\choose k}$ term for this calculation.

Explanations I ran into merely stated that there were $k$ places that are "taken", but it doesn't make much sense as they can't be taken until they are taken, I mean, it's more in retrospect.

How can I explain such a process? 
**Edit: the final answer is very clear to me, but the binomial expression is what I struggle with.**

Comment: There are $2n$ ways. If $i$ is red, so is $i-1$, so is $i-2$, $\ldots$. So, you only have one choice, choosing the last red element.

Comment: I don't look for the **final answer**. I am to present an identity. That's why I need help with the binomial expression.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the question correctly, I don't see why you use blue $i-1$ next to red $i$ where your question suggest something totally different.

Comment: Because there is an identity I am to arrive at, which uses inclusion and exclusion. Looking at forbidden coloring, I can use the principle. How come this principle not relevant?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean if $i$ is red, then $i-1$ is blue? At least that's what your coloring on the 4th line seems to imply. Also, how would you use inclusion-exclusion here?

Comment: @Soke He wants to count the bad cases and subtract them from the total number.

Comment: The problem as stated simply has nothing whatever to do with inclusion-exclusion! Which is why it seems likely you've stated the problem wrong...

Comment: Well this is what "Body of question" is for, where I described what I am trying to do and where I struggled.

Comment: Complementary counting is not the same thing as inclusion-exclusion, FYI.

Comment: Have I suggested it is the same? I'd appreciate an elaboration so that I can edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this you have $k$ BR blocks and $2n-2k$ unit blocks. So, you have $2n-k$ empty spots, and you want to choose $k$ spots out of these $2n-k$ to place BR blocks. B=blue,R=red

Comment: I am a little confused when it comes to having  $2n$ colored blue. It is legal and will leave me with $2n-(k+1)$ R blocks. How can I relate to that?

Comment: It appears to me that It doesn't matter actually. All channels could be what ever they are... That's the concept of Exclusion and Inclusion..

Comment: This is different from your comment.  Once you choose the highest number red, everything is determined-blue above because that is the highest red and red below by induction. I don't understand this answer

Comment: The OP does not want the solution, s/he wants to apply inclusion/exclusion to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1 must be blue: If I = 1 then i-1 doesn't exist and therefore isn't red, so it must be blue. If i=2 then I-1 is blue so 2 is blue, and so on. All i 
Must be blue.